# Linear trigonometric equation $\sin(x)=\cos(x)$

Tags: linear-algebra, trigonometry

I was solving an apparently simple equation but then it turned out I missed one of the solutions that somebody else find using another method.

$\cos x=\sin x$ was the problem.

I tried the associated angle method, so $\sin(x)=\cos\left(\frac{\pi}{2} - x\right)$.
Performing the substitution I could equal the argument of Cos  and solve the equation in $x$. It turned out I missed $5\pi/4 $ and I cannot understand why.
Can somebody explain me the right way to use this method?

Comment: Cosine isn't a one-to-one function, so $\cos(x)=\cos(y)$ doesn't imply that $x=y$

Comment: Welcome to MSE. Please tell us what you did.

Comment: I had to solve the equation that i mentioned.Basicly anyone would divide for Sin x and solve for Tan(x)=1 equation but i wanted to solve with associated angles.Using associated of Sin i found a solution what wasn't required and using associated of Cos i found just one of solution.. I would like to understand the way the reason when using associated angle,for any kind of associated.Thank to you

Answer (score 1):

Indeed, $\sin(x) = \cos(\frac\pi2 -x )$, therefore $\sin(x)=\cos(x)$ is equivalent to $\cos(\frac\pi2 -x ) = \cos(x)$.

However, note that trigonometric functions are periodic with a period of $2\pi$ and that cosine is an even function, i.e. $$\cos(x) = \cos(x + 2\pi k), \quad k \in \mathbb Z$$ and $$\cos(x) = \cos (-x),$$ or together $$\cos(x) = \cos(\pm x + 2\pi k), \quad k \in \mathbb Z.$$

Using this, $\sin(x)=\cos(x)$ becomes $$\frac\pi2 - x = \pm x + 2\pi k, \quad k \in \mathbb Z.$$

After rearranging, this finally becomes $$x = \left(n + \frac14\right)\pi, \quad k \in \mathbb Z.$$

Comment: Thank you Danijel,you have reorganized my ideas.

Answer (score 0):

So, we have $\dfrac\pi2-x=2n\pi\pm x$ where $n$ is any integer

Comment: Is this still a reasonable choice if i have to equal Sin(argument) ?

Answer (score 0):

$$\frac{\pi}{2} -x = x+ k2\pi$$
$$ -2x= -\frac{\pi}{2} +k2\pi$$
$$x= \frac{\pi}{4} - k\pi$$
Which for any integer $k$ , would give the correct result.

Answer (score 0):

Assume $\sin x = \cos x$.

If $\cos x = 0$ then $\sin^2x + \cos^2 x = 1 $ implies $\sin x = \pm 1$, which is a contradiction.

Therefore certainly $\cos x \ne 0$ so  $\sin x = \cos x$ implies $\tan x = \frac{\sin x}{\cos x} = 1$. Therefore $$x = \frac{\pi}4 + k\pi, \quad k \in \mathbb{Z}$$